# Why doesn't `addEventListener` accept a class method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I recently learned that the listener passed to `addEventListener` can be an object with a `handleEvent` function, instead of just a callback function. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#listener)

However, this doesn't seem to work when `handleEvent` is a class method:

```js
class Foo {
    static handleEvent() {
        console.log(`clicked`);
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener(`click`, Foo);
```

This throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Foo cannot be invoked without 'new'

This is trivial to work around -- I can simply pass in `Foo.handleEvent` instead. But for my own education, I'm wondering why `static handleEvent` doesn't work?

Comment: It said `object` and not `class`, those are different things.

Comment: because a class is not an instance  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)

Comment: `Foo instanceof Object` is `true`. Everything in Javascript is an object.

Answer (score 1):

It hit me!

`addEventListener` can accept either a function or an object with a `handleEvent` method.

`Foo` *is* an object -- `Foo instanceof Object` is `true` -- but it's *also* a constructor, which is a function.

So, `addEventListener` "sees" that `Foo` is *some kind of function* and treats it like any other function. That is: it tries to call `Foo()`.

This fails, since `Foo` is a *constructor* function and so cannot be called without `new`. `addEventListener` doesn't first check whether `Foo` is also an object that happens to have a `handleEvent` method.

Answer (score 1):

Section 1.3.1 of the [W3C Document Object Model Events specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) descibes an "IDL interface" of the listener:

```
// Introduced in DOM Level 2:
interface EventListener {
  void               handleEvent(in Event evt);
};
```

The Web IDL Standard specification, [section 2.5.7](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-static-attributes-and-operations), says:

> It is language binding specific whether it is possible to invoke a
> static operation or get or set a static attribute through a reference
> to an instance of the interface

It therefore looks to me like the implementation of the language binding, which supplies the event to a Javascript listener, decided not to allow calls to "static operations".

For example, there is an open bug report asking for Mozilla's implementation to be capable of calling static methods [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=863952), which is mentioned [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/dom/webIdlBindings/index.html#static-members)

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate an instance of the class. This would work:

```
class Foo {
    static handleEvent() {
        console.log(`clicked`);
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener(`click`, new Foo());
```

Without the `new` keyword, calling a function that is intended to be used as a constructor will simply execute the function without creating a new instance.

Basically, the ecmascript interpreter doesn't know how to properly handle instantiation of a class without the `new` keyword. It's just a feature of the language, and not specific to TypeScript or EventTarget/addEventListener.

Since `Foo` is a constructor, `addEventListener` just sees that it is a function and will attempt to call it. It doesn't know that it's a class, so it doesn't attempt to call the static `handleEvent` method.

```
typeof Foo
'function'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer the question, which is 'why' and not 'how': "Why doesn't `static handleEvent` work?"

Comment: Updated with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQA4FcBGIAlsNABZgB2AJiAKYCiAbrRQC4AUAlCuppgE61WOfhWjB4FCPDoA6EPADm7AAahiAa1pUVnANy8MAX1Qmq8YDgC2LVrLzwqAT1lgqVJrYAyhCKxa0-KrqwBoqADRwiLJY-PCs8U5YtLLk1HSebPpAA), there are "click" logs being fired left and right with or without adding the `abstract` keyword before the class definition

if you don't want to handle instantiating a new class via the `new` keyword (such as your error indicates) then you'd turn the targeted class into an abstract class which allows you to simply key-into the class without instantiating a new instance

```
abstract class Foo {
    static handleEvent() {
       return console.log(`clicked`);
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener(`click`, Foo.handleEvent);
```

Since your method is `static` however, it should work regardless by keying into the "handleEvent" method

```
class Foo {
    static handleEvent() {
       return console.log(`clicked`);
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener(`click`, Foo.handleEvent);
```

if you were to change the method from `static` to `public` for example, you'd simply have to key-into `prototype` following `Foo` as follows

```
class Foo {
    public handleEvent() {
       return console.log(`clicked`);
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener(`click`, Foo.prototype.handleEvent);
```